# Open file explorer and search for variable in textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I the user to enter a keyword in a text box and when the macro is executed;

- Open a new Windows' File Explorer window designated by a path.

  path = C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Folder7
- Search from the variable in SearchBox1 (this is a ActiveX text box on a worksheet.)

  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("SearchBox1").Object.Text & "*"

I saw multiple posts using Shell commands to open a File Explorer Window.

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "search-ms:query=*.pdf&crumb=location:C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Folder7" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```

When I run the above line there is an error from the explorer.

> 'Windows cannot find ". Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.'

I need the macro to search for all files associated with the string. Folder names, file names, and words/characters within each type of document. They have all been OCR'd and Indexed by Windows.

It should have the ability to search for incomplete words as well.

I got Shell to open an explorer window to the path by

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Folder7" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```

How can I search all folders and sub-folders within this freshly opened window?
I **don't** need the results compiled into Excel or any other program. I just need to make a quick search button as if you were to manually open this folder and use the search bar.

Comment: I may have gotten closer but now am stuck on my Variable within the string..

    Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Folder7&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A(""mySearch"")&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CME%5CDesktop%5CFolder7" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Double Click on Cell to search**

This is a solution I have combined from various places to open an explorer window at a path, that are filtered (searched) by the term in the selected cell using the windows File Explorer search function. It is triggered by a double click on a cell that contains the search term:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:AA1048576")) Is Nothing Then
Dim d As String
Dim searchpath As String
Dim searchlocation As String
Cancel = True
d = Selection.Value
'change window name to make sure new explorer window is opened for each instance
'copy string from manual search
searchpath = "search-ms:displayname=" & d & "%20Results%20&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A"
'copy string from manual search (e.g. my documents replace USERNAME)
searchlocation = "&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CUSERNAME%5CDocuments"
If Not d = "" Then
    Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & searchpath & d & searchlocation & "", 1)
   'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376850/open-explorer-search-from-excel-hyperlink
End If
End If
End Sub
```

This opens the window in VbNormalFocus, with the window title set to the cell variable (d). The ensures that if this code is run on another cell value a new separate window will be opened. Without this I found the next time I ran the code the explorer window was not updated with the new search value, but just changed focus to the previous result.

edit: "copy from search bar" is the string after location: in the address bar of a manual search in explorer

**Using ActiveX Controls**

Add an ActiveX Text box (TextBox1) and button (CommandButton1) and add the following codeto the command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim d As String
Dim searchpath As String
Dim searchlocation As String
Cancel = True
d = TextBox1.Value
'change window name to make sure new explorer window is opened for each instance
'copy string from manual search
searchpath = "search-ms:displayname=" & d & "%20Results%20&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A"
'copy string from manual search (e.g. my documents replace USERNAME)
searchlocation = "&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CUSERNAME%5CDocuments"
If Not d = "" Then
    Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & searchpath & d & searchlocation & "", 1)
   'src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376850/open-explorer-search-from-excel-hyperlink
End If
End Sub
```

Now the user can change the text in the text box and clicking the button will open a windows file explorer search of the designated folder in the code.

[Screenshot example using button search for "Editable Search Text"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Y40.png)

**EDIT**

You can include additional search functions with the Windows search syntax:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/7/8174a74e-3d8d-4478-abc6-84cd51ad93c4/Windows_Desktop_Advanced_Query_Reference.pdf

Eg. you can search within the folder for all files with a partial match of each word in the string by changing the search variable "d:

```
...
d = Selection.Value
d = "(" & Replace(d, " ", " OR ") & ")"
...
```

if the selection (d) had a value of `Where will I find it` 
This will search for `(Where OR will OR I OR find OR it)` in windows explorer and would return files with names such as `WHEREver` and `Last WILL and testament`. I've found this useful for qualitative information, where casting a wider search is acceptable and can be easily filtered through by the user (NOTE: the above example would also return all files with a name containing `i` so it is not very specific!)

Comment: thanks for responding. im a little confused. how do I have a activeX txt box or a txt field form control (does it matter which i use?), be the keyword for the search. i can't seam to figure out how to get your code to work.

Comment: This code was just a snippet from a sheet I had which captured a double click on a cell containing the search value. I'll update my answer with more details and specifically more about having a text box and ActiveX controls...

Comment: thanks for checking in. Yes, your explanation and pictures helped me understand. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Tester()
    ShowSearch "C:\_Stuff\test", "*.pdf"           'search by file name
    ShowSearch "C:\_Stuff\Mail\", "reminder", True 'search by keyword
End Sub


Sub ShowSearch(searchWhere, searchFor, Optional SearchByKeyword As Boolean = False)
    Const CMD As String = "explorer.exe ""search-ms:crumb=name:{query}&crumb=location:{location}"" "
    Dim s
    s = Replace(CMD, "{query}", WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(searchFor))
    s = Replace(s, "{location}", WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(searchWhere))
    If SearchByKeyword Then s = Replace(s, "crumb=name:", "crumb=")
    'Debug.Print s
    Shell s
End Sub
```

**Note**: `WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL()` is 2013 and later.  For alternatives see:

[How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

executing Dir() empty after a Dir() with a given path will start to list all files in that dir, you just use if InStr() <> 0 to check against your value.

```
sFileName = Dir(path)
Do While sFileName > ""
tmp = tmp & sFileName & ";" : sFileName = Dir()
Loop
List() = Split(tmp, ";")
```

there you have a list of all files inside that path, you can check sub folders the same way by going through each one doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure how this will search via my SearchBox1.

Answer (score 0):

I do not take credit for the idea, it's awesome that you can do this. I just took the idea a step further and made it modular, so you can add any type of search:

```
Sub searchInExplorer_TEST()
    'searchInExplorer "D:\", , , True, "*.jpg", True, "24 Feb 20"
    searchInExplorer "D:\", , , , , True, "24 Feb 20", True, "picture"
End Sub


Sub searchInExplorer(searchWhere _
                    , Optional isSearchAll As Boolean, Optional strAll _
                    , Optional isSearchName As Boolean, Optional strName _
                    , Optional isSearchModified As Boolean, Optional strModified _
                    , Optional isSearchType As Boolean, Optional strType)
    
    '*****************************************************
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671500/vba-to-open-file-explorer-and-search-for-variable-in-textbox
    'ALLOWS SEARCHING IN WINDOWS EXPLORER USING VARIABLES
    'EITHER USE SEARCH ALL OR OTHER SEARCH TIMES
    'EACH SEARCH TYPE HAS AN ON/OFF SWITCH AND A STRING VARIABLE TO SEARCH BY
    '*****************************************************
        
    Dim STR As String
    
    STR = "explorer.exe ""search-ms:"
    If isSearchAll Then
        STR = STR & "crumb=:" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strAll)
        
    Else
        If isSearchName Then
            STR = STR & "&crumb=name:" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strName)
        End If
        
        If isSearchModified Then
            STR = STR & "&crumb=modified:" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strModified)
        End If
        
        If isSearchType Then
            STR = STR & "&crumb=kind:" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(strType)
        End If
        
    End If
    
    STR = STR & "&crumb=location:" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(searchWhere)
    STR = STR & """ "
    
    Debug.Print STR
    Shell STR
End Sub
```